# What is "if not" equivalent for "else" and "elif"?

Tags: python, windows, if-statement

I'm new to python. I need help.
What is the proper syntax (if any) for this scenario?

```
if blabla:
    if not blablabla:
        print ("Some code..")

    elif not blablabla:
        print("Some other code..")

    else:
        print("Final code")
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Except for the unbalanced quotes (I assume the first `"` should have been a `:`?) and that `bla bla bla` is not anything meaningful, this is valid Python.  What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Seemingly a white space is fine. Oops.

Assuming you define `x`, `y`, and `z`, your code will work properly if you use it correctly.

Defining `x` is true always:

- If `y = False` and `z = True`, output is `Some code...`
- If `y` and `z` are `True`, then the output is `Final Code`
- If `y` and `z` are `False`, the output is `Some code...`
- If `y = True` and `z = False`, then the output is `Some other code...`

If `x = False` then nothing will run and will automatically finished because the only way the `if x:` will run is when `x` is not `False`. Also, change the `"` to a `:` on the first line to prevent the inevitable error.

Comment: *since the parentheses aren't in the right place* -- if you're complaining about the space then no, that doesn't matter.  whitespace between tokens is ignored. You could have `if a . f   ( x ) :`

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. Thanks for the remind!